# How can track write progress when piping with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, progress-bar

I am trying to track the progress of a pipe from a read stream to write stream so I can display the progress to the user.

My original idea was to track progress when the `data` event is emitted as shown here:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let final = fs.createWriteStream('output');

fs.createReadStream('file')
    .on('close', () => {
        console.log('done');
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("data");
        /* Calculate progress */
    })
    .pipe(final);
```

However I realized just cause it was read, doesn't mean it was actually written. This can be seen if the `pipe` is removed, as the `data` event still emits.

How can track **write** progress when piping with Node.js?

Comment: If it adds any meaningful value to his thread, you may want to look into node.js buffers

Answer (score 7):

You can use a dummy Transform stream like this:

```
const stream = require('stream');

let totalBytes = 0;
stream.pipeline(
    fs.createReadStream(from_file),
    new stream.Transform({
        transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            totalBytes += chunk.length;
            console.log(totalBytes);
            this.push(chunk);
            callback();
        }
    }),
    fs.createWriteStream(to_file),
    err => {
        if (err)
            ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the piping manually, and make use of the `callback` from [writable.write()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback)

> `callback`: < function > Callback for when this chunk of data is flushed

```
const fs = require('fs');

let from_file = `<from_file>`;
let to_file = '<to_file>';

let from_stream = fs.createReadStream(from_file);
let to_stream   = fs.createWriteStream(to_file);

// get total size of the file
let { size } = fs.statSync(from_file);

let written = 0;
from_stream.on('data', data => {
    // do the piping manually here.
    to_stream.write(data, () => {
        written += data.length;
        console.log(`written ${written} of ${size} bytes (${(written/size*100).toFixed(2)}%)`);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried similar things before but all the data is kept in memory which causes the application to crash for large files. That is why I used pipe. Will this not keep the data in memory?

Comment: This should have minimal memory usage, if in doubt, you could add `process.memoryUsage()` within the event loop and monitor the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I remember this thread being about memory efficiency, anyway, I've rigged up a small script that's very memory efficient and tracks progress very well. I tested it under a 230MB file and the result speaks for itself. https://gist.github.com/J-Cake/78ce059972595823243526e022e327e4

The sample file I used was a bit weird as the `content-length` header it reported was in fact off but the program uses no more than 4.5 MiB of memory.